# Index.html is missing while generating reactjs build. How can we deploy react and nodejs project to production?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, build

I have created my project with Create React App and for a server using nodeJs but when deploying to production, the file index.html is missing in build folder. I've checked the public folder and the template of index.html is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to *react-create-app* documentation. [Creating a production build](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/production-build/)

Comment: Because? It describes what to do when index.html is not generated?

Answer (score 0):

When running in development mode, `create-react-app` spins up a server that serves everything from the public folder.

Thus, in production, your express app also needs to serve everything from the public folder.

```
server.use(express.static("public"));
```